# (Unauthorized) when requesting from localhost - no errors when "node testRequest.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, request

I am scraping a website that requires login. When I just run a local test function to test my requests everything works fine.

Here is the weird part. Everything works fine, when I run my script on the client side, but when it is run on the server side on my localhost server I get the an error after succesfully logged in. This error accures when I attempts to make a GET request to the target websites api. The error I get is: **401 (Unauthorized)** Error. The res msg is: **{Message: "Authorization has been denied for this request."}**

I think that the website I am trying to scrape is blocking external api requests made from other websites, which explains the error when I run the script on the server side of my localhost.

Let's assume this is the case. **How should I go about avoiding the server from corssorigin blocking my requests?**

---

**Me running it client side: https://gyazo.com/ec8fb27ef9a679413eed04f5c4acf475**

**Me running it server side: https://gyazo.com/43096da6c5f381c0faa39ced92a0108c**

---

**Please note:** Everything works fine when running the script on the client side, I get no errors whatsoever, everyting just works as expected.

But when I run the exact same script from the server side of my application, things start to get weird. I am somehow able to succesfully login but thereafter all of my GET requests to their api results in the 401 unauthorized error.

---

script.js - feel free to login using my username and password.  (the indent is a little off.)

```
    const Async = require('simplify-async').simpleAsync;
    var request = require('request');
    var request = request.defaults({jar: true, headers: {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"}});

    const formData = {
        username: 'zinuku.public@gmail.com',
        password: 'Ryan1234',
        grant_type: 'password'
    };

    const options = {
        url: 'https://www.eovendo.com/token',
        form: formData,
        referer: 'https://www.eovendo.com/',
    };


    const callback = (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {console.log(err, 'FAILED'); return}

        const info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info);
        console.log('Succesfully logged in');


        const getBalance = () => {
            console.log('WE AR ENOW IN GET BALANCE');
            const promise = new Async();

            request.get({url: 'https://www.eovendo.com/api/Balance/GetBalance'}, (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) promise.reject(err);
                const balance = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log('>>>', balance);
                promise.resolve(balance)
            });
            return promise.promise;
        };

        getBalance()
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('balance func response, msg:', res)
                });
    };

    const eo_login = (options) => {
        request.post(options, callback);
    };

    eo_login(options);
```

Comment: You should not try to hack your way around websites to crawl their content if they do not want to allow crawling.

Comment: @LajosArpad My only goal with this is to log into my profile and get my status, that is it. As far as I know they have no rules against that.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume here that you have logged in to the service, but you do not properly send the session id to it. Take a look at your browser's network tab when you are logging in and doing requests and see what is being sent to the server and what is being received. By mimiking the communication between your user browser and their server you will be able to log in and crawl. But do not do that if they do not want to allow you to do so.

Comment: Well I am able to do so but it only works when I run the script on the client side, when I try to run it from the server side I get the 401 unauthorized error after logging in and attempting to make a GET request to their api.

Comment: @RyanCameron this means that your code at the server-side has a flaw. Can you show us the code?

Comment: @RyanCameron your browser clearly resolves the problem your server fails to resolve. I suppose you have a session id or something which should be sent. How are the requests sent by the browser looking alike?